# What are the closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to find what the closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ are. I know that the prime ideals of $\mathbb Z$ are the ideals generated by prime numbers, i.e., the prime ideals of $\mathbb Z$ are $(p)$, where $p$ is a prime number.

My reasoning:

If $a$ is prime, then $V((a))=(a)$, if $V(a) \neq \emptyset$, am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$V(a)$ is the set of prime ideals CONTAINING $a$. Now, what numbers would be in the prime ideal $(2)$?

Also, there is an extra prime ideal you're forgetting. What are the ideals of a field? Which of them are prime?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It occurred to me after writing the following answer that the OP may not be familiar with schemes and only be using ''$\text{Spec}$" for the set of primes with the Zariski topology. In such a case this is not a good answer, but others may find it useful.

The closed subschemes of any affine scheme are in 1-1 correspondence with ideals of the corresponding ring. If one only wants closed subsets (i.e. forget scheme structure), then it is typical to limit it to radical ideals (i.e. $I$ and $I^2$ give the same closed subset). So the following questions remain, depending on whether you want closed subschemes or closed subsets.

1. What are the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$.
2. What are the radical ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$.